# Android Studio 1.1 warning with switch case statement

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a branch which replace system day of week integer value to human readable string value.

When I use if-else statement like the following, Android Studio 1.1 does not warn anything.

```
int intDayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
String curStrDayOfWeek = "";
if (intDayOfWeek == 1) {
    curStrDayOfWeek = getResources().getString(R.string.sunday);
}
else if(intDayOfWeek == 2) {
    curStrDayOfWeek = getResources().getString(R.string.monday);
}
else if(intDayOfWeek == 3) {
    curStrDayOfWeek = getResources().getString(R.string.tuesday);
}
[SNIP]

globals = (Globals) this.getApplication();

try {
    [SNIP]
    globals.hdsr_data.put("currentDayOfWeek", curStrDayOfWeek);
    [SNIP]
catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error:" + e);
    }
   [SNIP]
```

But if I try to use switch-case statement like the following, it warns the value getResources().getString(R.string.sunday) assigned to curStrDayOfWeek is never used.  Then I got 6 warnings since value have 7 branch.

```
int intDayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
switch (intDayOfWeek) {
    case 1 : curStrDayOfWeek = getResources().getString(R.string.sunday);
    case 2 : curStrDayOfWeek = getResources().getString(R.string.monday);
    case 3 : curStrDayOfWeek = getResources().getString(R.string.tuesday);
[SNIP]
}
```

I'd like to code without warning (Except typo).  How can I use switch-case statement without warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But if I try to use switch-case statement like the following, it warns the value `getResources().getString(R.string.sunday)` assigned to `curStrDayOfWeek` is never used.

And it's absolutely right - because you'd immediately fall through to the next branch. You need a `break` statement:

```
switch (intDayOfWeek) {
    case 1:
        curStrDayOfWeek = getResources().getString(R.string.sunday);
        break;
    case 2:
        curStrDayOfWeek = getResources().getString(R.string.monday);
        break;
    case 3:
        curStrDayOfWeek = getResources().getString(R.string.tuesday);
        break;
    ...
}
```

Personally I'd probably just build an array though:

```
private static final int[] DAY_NAME_RESOURCES = {
    0, // not used
    R.string.sunday,
    R.string.monday,
    R.string.tuesday,
    ...
};
```

Then use:

```
curStrDayOfWeek = getResource().getString(DAY_NAME_RESOURCES[i]);
```